# How to port an Ajax CMS based on metadata in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, web-services, content-management-system, metadata

I'm maintaining a CMS where I have this feeling it was made in the age of dinosaurs (Asp.net 1.0?) and decided to upgrade it with [Asp.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). But I have some problems regarding the design/specifications of the CMS which I cannot change.

**The CMS**

The CMS uses JavaScript. A lot. As in "I don't load pages, I request new pages using Ajax and render the information using javascript" a lot.
Not to mention the animations, the weird horizontal apresentation of structures... anyways, besides the first page (that is the login page) every other "page" is just data requested from a ***WebService*** that comes with the website.
Would MVC have any problems with this design?

**The Database**

The database is in a SQL Server 2k8 and, like the CMS, this part is also... interesting.
Basically, the user can create data structures using metadata (and saved on the Structure table). These structures are saved on tables that are created (and regenerated when changed) at runtime using said metadata.
I don't know how I would implement this part in MVC.

The question is, can and **should** I convert this project to MVC?
Any tips regarding the metadata and overuse of ajax?

*Edit*:
[Wyatt Barnett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107694/wyatt-barnett) told me to run, and I agree. I really, *really* want to run away.
Unfortunately I can't, I need this job. * *sigh* *

Comment: Why would you? You have basically 2 pages. I think that's a REALLY poor design, but that aside, converting to MVC would be overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about this for a while I decided to forego MVC since it didn't exactly fit for such project.

I'm currently cleaning the project and using a single page that loads the main javascript code (which will load the specific javascript code for each situation).

The Webservice will basically connect the client with the server and manage sessions to prevent unauthorized use.